# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file - WordPress Plugin

Tags: php

I just bought one WordPress plugin and trying to activate using dashboard. I tried to solve this myself but not getting any success.

**Error**

```
 '2'); ?>
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
```

**My Code**

```
<?php

function sourceGuard_cp(){

global $sourceGuard_settings;
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>Source Guard Settings</h2>


<?
$current_mode = $sourceGuard_settings['mode'];

$enabled_modules = array('html_obfuscator' => false, 'js_encoder' => false);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    if(($_POST['html_obfuscator'] == 1) && ($_POST['js_encoder'] == 1)){

        $new_mode = '3';
    }
    else if($_POST['html_obfuscator'] == 1){

        $new_mode = '1';
    }
    else if($_POST['js_encoder'] == 1){

        $new_mode = '2';
    }
    else{

        $new_mode = '0';
    }


    if($fp = @fopen(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'settings.php', 'w')){

        $current_mode = $new_mode;

        fwrite($fp, "<?\n\$sourceGuard_settings = array('mode' => '".$current_mode."');\n?>");
        fclose($fp);

        echo '<div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="updated settings-error"> <p><strong>Settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
    }
    else{

        echo '<div id="setting-error-settings_updated" class="error settings-error"> <p><strong>Settings cant be saved!</strong></p></div>';
    }
}

switch($current_mode){

    case '1';
        //html obfuscation

        $enabled_modules['html_obfuscator'] = true;
    break;
    case '2';
        //js encoding

        $enabled_modules['js_encoder'] = true;
    break;
    case '3';
        //html+js

        $enabled_modules['html_obfuscator'] = true;
        $enabled_modules['js_encoder'] = true;
    break;
}
?>


<form action="" method="POST">
<h3>Available modules</h3>

<table class="form-table">

<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label>HTML obfuscation</label></th>
<td>

    <label><input name="html_obfuscator" type="radio" value="1" autocomplete="off"<?=($enabled_modules['html_obfuscator'])?' checked':'';?>>&nbsp; <span>Enabled</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label><input name="html_obfuscator" type="radio" value="0" autocomplete="off"<?=(!$enabled_modules['html_obfuscator'])?' checked':'';?>>&nbsp; <span>Disabled</span></label>
</td>
</tr>
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label>JavaScript encoding</label></th>
<td>

    <label><input name="js_encoder" type="radio" value="1" autocomplete="off"<?=($enabled_modules['js_encoder'])?' checked':'';?>>&nbsp; <span>Enabled</span></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <label><input name="js_encoder" type="radio" value="0" autocomplete="off"<?=(!$enabled_modules['js_encoder'])?' checked':'';?>>&nbsp; <span>Disabled</span></label>
</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</table>

<p class="submit"><input name="submit" id="submit" class="button-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit"></p>
</form>
</div>
<?
}
?>
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to activate one plugin in my WordPress dashboard.

Please help me to solve the issue.

Comment: Make sure you have [`short_open_tag`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) enabled.

Comment: or just change all `<?` to `<?php`

Answer (score 4):

Try replacing all the `<?` with `<?php`

You can also try removing the last `?>` and the ending of the code.

Comment: I was having the same problem and in my case it was having the short version of the PHP tag. Replacing them with <?php did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried by using a Clean system catch, including Error reporting, DNS catch. It works fine for me.